# Which dataflow region should be used when bigquery data in Europe (EU)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dataflow

I am trying to create a SQL dataflow job that publishes to Pub/Sub. I am getting an error whenever I run a job saying that the table cannot be found. I have assumed this is due to the region being incorrect, but I cannot work out which region I should use.

I can only query my tables in bigquery if I select the 'Processing location' as "Europe (EU)" (under query settings), this is not available as a region in dataflow.  If I select any of the "europe-west-X" processing locations in bigquery then I get an error stating that table cannot be found.

If I select one of these regions in dataflow then get the following error when running the dataflow job:

```
Invalid table specification in Data Catalog: Could not resolve table in Data Catalog: bigquery.table.`project_name`.dataset.model
```

Comment: our company moved in BigQuery all tables from EU to a single region "europe-west-X" during the introduction of dataflow, maybe there was a reson for that.

Comment: how are you running your data flow job? I mean are you creating your own template? Could you please provide more details? Also, what is the region you have your big query data in? europe-north1 or europe-west1 or europe-west4?